# CouchDB throws conflict error after immediate update

Tags: couchdb

I'm using CouchDB 1.5 and trying to fix some values in documents with a rather simple request. I simply `get` a document, modify a value in it and then `put` it back immediately. Given that my database has low usage, I don't expect this simple operation to produce a conflict. And yet, the 85 documents belonging to 85 different users all fail to update with conflict errors, with no apparent reasons.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

var couchdbUrl = 'https://USER:PASS@DOMAIN.COM';

var usersDb = new PouchDB(`${couchdbUrl}/_users`, {
    skip_setup: true
});

usersDb.query('faulty_users/object_username', {
        include_docs: true
    })
    .then((userDocs) => {
        userDocs.rows
            .forEach(function(userDoc) {
                userDb = new PouchDB(`${couchdbUrl}/user%2F${userDoc.doc.hoodieId}`);

                userDb.get('accountvalues/default', {
                        conflicts: true
                    })
                    .then((doc) => {
                        console.log(doc._id, doc._rev, doc._conflicts);

                        doc.values.accountValues.username = userDoc.doc.name.replace(/^user\//, '');

                        userDb.put(doc)
                            .catch((e) => {
                                console.log(userDoc.doc.hoodieId, e);
                            });
                    });
            });
    });
```

I've read and read again the documentation of PouchDB and I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I hope the error will be pretty obvious to someone here :-)

Comment: I don't know this API or PouchDB but I see you are creating a new connection in a loop. Might be the problem?

Comment: Nope, I don't believe the problem lies here, as PouchDB isn't actually creating connections when `new PouchDB()` is used.

Comment: Is it possible that your view returns 2 times the same document (async problems could occurs). Even if you call the put right after the get, don't forget that you're working on async. Maybe the same document is called twice. Normally you could see if you have any duplicates id with your console.log(doc._id, ..)

Comment: I haven't use Pouch myself but maybe just worth checking whether the revision on the updated document you are sending back is correct?

Comment: Are you sure that this code tries to put the docs into the correct database? Isn't userDb already a different database, when the get-promise is fulfilled and userDb.put is called? Could you share part of your couchdb log?